# "No such file or directory" - but the file I want to open is right there

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using a little `loader.py` file, that opens a `.gz` file:

```
---> 38     f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mnist.pkl.gz'
```

I had this problem when loading the `loader.py` file as well, but I fixed it by doing:

```
sys.path
sys.path.append   -- and adding the right folder to the directory.
```

But the `.gz` file is in the same folder, so I don't understand how it can find one but not the other?

I am very new to Python so please be gentle (done loads of Matlab but I'm trying to work through some machine learning code).

Comment: Your current directory may not be the same as the directory where the file is.

Comment: `sys.path` only affects where Python looks for modules, it has no effect on file operations in general.  Use a full pathname, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, how can I change my current directory then? - or is it better to specify fiull pathname (but then I can see my code getting very cluttered, and I'll have to go into every file and change it all)

Comment: So... how can I change my current directory to the one where the file is?